# Tracking user replies in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to track how many users have replied in my firebase DB, and I'm wondering what the best workflow is. I want to send a notification to the last user to reply.

My firebase Db is organised like so currently

```
├── chat 
│   ├── -M5D96yP5Ac688-ZPU0C << chatId 1
│   │   ├── info
│   │   │   ├── groupName: Breakfast Club
│   │   │   ├── id: -M5D96yP5Ac688-ZPU0C
│   │   │   ├── last_reply_from: 8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1
│   │   │   ├── no_of_users: 4
│   │   │   └── Users:
│   │   │       ├── 8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1: true
│   │   │       ├── QvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: false
│   │   │       ├── y1EKihfmIJTDCD9OJt0N89WDC643: false
│   │   │       └── zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: false
│   │   └──Messages
│   │           .....
├── user
```

And I was going to do the following.

1. count the amount of users and add to "no_of_users" field uing getChildrenCount()
2. count how many users have true as their value
3. subtract one from the other, and if == 1 then send notification
4. reset all users values to false, and start again.

```
    private void checkReplies() {
         final DatabaseReference chatInfoDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").child(mChatObject.getChatId()).child("info").child("users");
         final DatabaseReference numberOfUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").child(mChatObject.getChatId()).child("info").child("no_of_users");
         Query query = chatInfoDb.orderByValue().equalTo(true);
         query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 final long howManyReplies = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                 System.out.println("How many users have replied " + howManyReplies);

                 numberOfUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                         long numberOfUser = (long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                         long maths = numberOfUser - howManyReplies;

                         if(maths == 1){
                             Query query = chatInfoDb.orderByValue().equalTo(false);
                             query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                     for(DataSnapshot childsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                         String lastToReply = childsnapshot.getKey();

                                         runSomethingElse(lastToReply);
                                     }
                                 }
                                 @Override
                                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                     }
```

But now I'm wondering if it would be better to have a "replied" node, and add users to it as they reply, then use myRef.removeValue() to clear out all replies. That seems like it'd be easier than looping through all the users to set them to false again.
e.g.

```
│   ├── -M5D96yP5Ac688-ZPU0C << chatId 1
│   │   ├── info
│   │   │   ├── groupName: Breakfast Club
│   │   │   ├── id: -M5D96yP5Ac688-ZPU0C
│   │   │   ├── last_reply_from: 8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1
│   │   │   ├── no_of_users: 4
│   │   │   ├── Users:
│   │   │   │   ├── 8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1: true
│   │   │   │   ├── QvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: true
│   │   │   │   ├── y1EKihfmIJTDCD9OJt0N89WDC643: true
│   │   │   │   └── zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: true
│   │   │   └── replies:
│   │   │       ├── 8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1: true
│   │   │       └── zQvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: true
│   │   └──Messages
│   │           .....
```

Which of these would be the more efficient workflow for this? Or is there another way to track this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: you want to send a notification to every user who has replied to you ?

Comment: No, I want to send a notification to the last user to respond. So if there are four users, when three have replied, send a notification to the forth person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of complicating your nodes like this, have a `super node` that tracks replies of a certain chat ID, everytime a user replies add their IDs to this `super node`. Something like that:

```
Replies
|
|
|-------------M5D96yP5Ac688-ZPU0C << chatId 1
              |
               -----8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1: true
               -----QvmGG2vPfTrdjZBfWP2ZotajYE3: true
|
|
|-------------QRE36yP5Ac688-ZPU0C << chatId 2
              | 
               -----8J7PX3ezjMTuOiAPO1BbOGJGP1g1: true
```

**Whenever you want to check who didn't reply yet**

when you enter the chat loop through the users in the chat and check if there ids exist in this super node, if not then send notification. After that just delete the chatID form the super node. And start over.

**UPDATE:**

I will explain one more time.

Ofcourse I assume that you have the list of UIDs in the chat from your datbase I see that. Now these are the steps to know which user replied and which didn't:

1) When user replies add his/her UID in the `supernode` under `Replies/chatID`.

2) Until now this means the existance of the UID of the user under `Replies/chatID` means that they replied.

3) When you want to check which user replied, you run a query over the users of the current chat, and loop through them. And check if their UIDs exist under `Replies/chatID`. If yes they replied, if no they didn't reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting idea, so would this have a lesser overhead than keeping everything grouped under the chatId?

Comment: It is a cleaner way, than putting everything in one place. But it is better than your first approach ofcourse. I think there is nothing better you can do.

Comment: Ok I see thanks. Having everything under the one node makes it quite easy to create all the data using a hashmap though. I can very quickly populate all the necessary children in one snippet.

Comment: So I've tried this out and have come up against an issue. How do I figure out which user has NOT replied. How can I compare the reply list with the user list and return the UID of the user that is missing? Thanks again

Comment: In that  super node you save `userID` which means to know if the user has replied you just check if his/her UID exists in this node `Replies/chatID`

Comment: I explained that in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I'm still not getting it, sorry I'm a noob. If I don't have a UID to compare against. But I have a user list with 4 entries, and a reply list with 3 entries. How do I find which UID is missing.

Comment: Ok I think I got it, I'll have a go at looping throught the two lists, much obliged!